loading an svg externally in canvas in fabric js
I want to upload individually all the elements in my svg into to my canvas.
you can see in the console [screenshot of the console(https://i.sstatic.net/Yj3SGXEx.png) that the svg file path is right and the console logs the content properly.
this is my code to upload the svg to my canvas
// URL of the external SVG file
const svgUrl = '../111.svg'; // Replace with your SVG URL

// Load the SVG file
fabric.loadSVGFromURL(svgUrl, (objects, options) => {
    console.log('SVG loaded:', objects);

    // Add objects to the canvas
    if (Array.isArray(objects)) {
        objects.forEach(obj => {
            canvas.add(obj);
        });
    } else {
        canvas.add(objects);
    }

    // Render the canvas
    canvas.renderAll();
}, (error) => {
    console.error('Error loading SVG:', error);
});


 var site_url = "./sample.svg"; // in public folder
fabric.loadSVGFromURL(site_url).then((o) => {
  o?.objects.forEach((element) => {
    canvas.add(element);
  });
});
canvas.renderAll();

https://qx2h66.csb.app/   from public folder
https://6ntx6x.csb.app/    from same folder
